Why does a network interface need to have a routing table entry configured to answer ARP requests?
I'm using a fresh minimal Ubuntu server 24.04.1 LTS install. I run these commands as root to set up networking and do some experiments:
apt install -y netcat-traditional tcpdump inetutils-ping

ip netns add ns1
ip netns add ns2

ip link add my_veth1 type veth peer name my_veth2

ip link set my_veth1 up netns ns1
ip link set my_veth2 up netns ns2

ip -n ns1 address add 1.2.3.4 dev my_veth1
ip -n ns1 route add 2.3.4.0/24 dev my_veth1

ip -n ns2 address add 2.3.4.5 dev my_veth2

Then I run these commands in different terminals:
# Terminal 1
ip netns exec ns1 tcpdump -l -i my_veth1

# Terminal 2
ip netns exec ns2 tcpdump -l -i my_veth2

# Terminal 3
ip netns exec ns1 ping 2.3.4.5

I get the same output in terminals 1 and 2:
02:40:27.511438 ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
02:40:27.511438 ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
02:40:27.511438 ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
...

veth2 has the IP address 2.3.4.5 and is receiving the ARP request. Why doesn't it send an answer? It only answers when I configure a routing table entry:
ip -n ns2 route add 1.2.3.0/24 dev my_veth2

But it shouldn't be necessary since the MAC address of the network interface that veth2 should respond to is already encoded in the request it is responding to.

ARP is an IP layer protocol; the kernel assumes, by default, that there's no point in responding to ARP requests from addresses that aren't reachable by any route.
If you're curious about the specific kernel logic, it starts in net/ipv4/arp.c in the arp_rcv function, which arranges to call arp_process, which calls ip_route_input_noref, which is what ultimately causes the packet to get dropped because the address is unreachable.
You can change the behavior a bit by disabling the rp_filter sysctl, which can take the following values:

0 - No source validation.

1 - Strict mode as defined in RFC3704.
Strict Reverse Path: Each incoming packet is tested against the FIB and if the interface is not the best reverse path the packet check will fail. By default failed packets are discarded.

2 - Loose mode as defined in RFC3704.
Loose Reverse Path: Each incoming packet’s source address is also tested against the FIB and if the source address is not reachable via any interface the packet check will fail.


If you disable source validation by setting rp_filter to 0:
ip netns exec ns2 sysctl net.ipv4.conf.my_veth2.rp_filter=0
ip netns exec ns2 sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0

The value used is the greatest of my_veth2 and all so we need to disable it for all too (on my system, the all value was already 0, but this won't always be the case so it's best to set it explicitly).
Then you will see that the kernel actually responds to the ARP request. If I run run ip netns exec ns1 ping 2.3.4.5, I see the following in ns1:
08:36:00.463621 my_veth1 Out ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
08:36:00.463666 my_veth1 In  ARP, Reply 2.3.4.5 is-at 5a:69:5d:ef:1e:5f, length 28
08:36:00.463672 my_veth1 Out IP 1.2.3.4 > 2.3.4.5: ICMP echo request, id 15496, seq 1, length 64

And in ns2:
08:36:00.463628 ARP, Request who-has 2.3.4.5 tell 1.2.3.4, length 28
08:36:00.463664 ARP, Reply 2.3.4.5 is-at 5a:69:5d:ef:1e:5f, length 28
08:36:00.463673 IP 1.2.3.4 > 2.3.4.5: ICMP echo request, id 15496, seq 1, length 64

With source validation disabled, the kernel responds to the ARP request, but the two namespaces cannot communicate because there is still no route from ns2 to ns1, so there is no way for ns2 to respond to the ping request.

You might have the arp_ignore sysctl set to 2.
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.{all,default,my_veth2}.arp_ignore

Traditionally Linux answers ARP for local addresses belonging to all interfaces (i.e. as if the addresses belong to the host as a whole), e.g. eth0 will answer with its own MAC address on behalf of local addresses assigned to eth2. Often that's unexpected (and I can't think of many situations where it would be of any use) and many admins disable that behavior by setting arp_ignore=1 which makes Linux only answer ARP for addresses assigned to that same interface. (This is how IPv6 NDP always behaves on Linux, and also the same as how IPv4 ARP behaves on several other operating systems, so arp_ignore=1 is generally a good choice.)
But some systems go further and use arp_ignore=2 which additionally suppresses ARP responses if the sender's IP address (which is also encoded in ARP queries) is not "part of the same subnet," which in Linux terms is determined by checking whether there's a link route to it. Such a restriction might make sense in some situations where multiple IP subnets share the same Ethernet broadcast domain... although generally such ARP requests (like yours) don't occur in normal use.

Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst
arp_ignore - INTEGER
    Define different modes for sending replies in response to
    received ARP requests that resolve local target IP addresses:

    - 0 - (default): reply for any local target IP address, configured
      on any interface
    - 1 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
      configured on the incoming interface
    - 2 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
      configured on the incoming interface and both with the
      sender's IP address are part from same subnet on this interface
    - 3 - do not reply for local addresses configured with scope host,
      only resolutions for global and link addresses are replied
    - 4-7 - reserved
    - 8 - do not reply for all local addresses

    The max value from conf/{all,interface}/arp_ignore is used
    when ARP request is received on the {interface}

There is another similar sysctl, arp_filter, where the condition is "…whether or not the kernel would route a packet from the ARP'd IP out that interface (therefore you must use source based routing for this to work)."

I had arp_ignore set to 0. The problem ended up being arp_filter. Thank you anyways.
